# Change description of Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, wording

*Feel free to respond with what you think it should be. Clearly there is some disagreement*

In the description of Stack Exchange, it says [on its homepage](https://stackexchange.com/):

> ...diverse topics from software programming to cooking to photography and gaming.

The way this is phrased makes it sound confusing. I would write it as

> ...diverse topics from software programming to cooking, photography to gaming.

If there is an English Major (or higher) who would care to correct me, please do. Otherwise, I will gladly accept explanations. Either way, it would ease my brain.

---

**Update:** I [posted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63721/what-is-the-correct-way-to-phrase-this/) on english.stackexchange.com, and came up with this:

> ...diverse topics including programming, cooking, photography and gaming.

I guess that makes my feature request this...

Could "...diverse topics from software programming to cooking to photography and gaming." be changed to "..diverse topics including programming, cooking, photography and gaming."?

Comment: Well, you could post this on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) for the best phrasing ;)

Comment: It should probably be "diverse topics from software programming to cooking, photography, and gaming."

Comment: I would go with "diverse topics from software programming to cooking, photography, gaming **and many more.**"

Comment: (Note that [the About Us](http://stackexchange.com/about) is much more verbose.)

Comment: Or perhaps just, _Stack Exchange is a fast-growing network of 85 question and answer sites on diverse topics._

Comment: @Arjan Yes, but first impressions make a big difference.

Comment: Agree with @M.Babcock: people can figure out what "diverse topics" might mean. There's no reason to limit ourselves or constrain people's imagination. Plus, his proposal is much simpler to read and understand.

Comment: @Oded See my update

Comment: the first sentence (the actual one) makes more sense than the one you suggested imo. the comma in yours is just awkward. The "from" that is lacking in the version from english.se adds to the sense of wide range, the "including" almost sounds pathetic. Seriously just leave it as it is.